How to add "..." in the middle when text more than 2 line in ReactJS
I want to display when text <=2 lines, then display 2 lines without "...".
However, if the text is > 2 lines, then add "..." in the middle.
In my code, i can add "..." in the middle, but when the text is less than or equal to 2 lines it still displays "...". I want is that when text <= 2 lines it still displays full text, and if text > 2 then displays "..." in the middle.
this is my code:
const Main=()=>{
return(
 <div>
   <p>{truncateMiddle(textDummy)}</p>
 </div>
)

const truncateMiddle=(text)=>{
  const offset = 50;
  const ellipsis = '...'
  const len = text.length;
  const tail = text.slice(len - offset, len);
  let head = ""

  let end = len - offset;
  let start = 50;

  while (start < end - 1) {
    const curr = Math.floor((end - start) / 2 + start);
    head = text.slice(0, curr);
    end = curr;
  }
  head = text.slice(0, start || 1);
  return head + ellipsis + tail;
}

for example if i have text >2 line like this:
"aaaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc
ddddd ffffff gggggg
hhhhh iiiiii jjjjjj"

then become like this:
"aaaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc
hh...... iiiiii jjjjjj"

and when i have text <=2 line:
"aaaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc
 ddddd ffffff gggggggggg"

and the result still 2 line
"aaaaaaa bbbbbbb ccccccc
 ddddd ffffff gggggggggg"


If you're looking for search terms, to remove text and replace it with an ellipsis is to elide the text.  (eliding, elision).  Also there is a Unicode character for it, which is … U+2026 : HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS {three dot leader}  or "\u2026" in JavaScript.

What if using pure CSS instead?
p {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2; // number of lines
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


no, i want make function for that to view in my pdf code in reactJS

View PDF? You didn't mention it in the question.
